# Visual Studio 2008 doesn't connect to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio, connection

When I try to make a new data connection from a Visual Studio 2008 to a database on SQL Server 2008, it fails. It says, it supports SQL Server connections up to SQL Server 2005 version only.

What is missing in my installation? Or where are settings I should change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install the Visual Studio 2008 service pack 1.

See [Microsoft Support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc440724.aspx) for more information.